# CodeSign error: code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 9.1'

Tags: codesign, ios9.1, xcode7.1

The apps is working fine in debug and throw error when I try to build it.
I have already regenerate certificate and provisioning profile, but nothing seems works.
I have gone through all answer for code sign error in here but also no solution.

How to fix this?

Comment: What exactly is the error?

Comment: I mean code sign error

Answer (score 3):

Go into your project **Build Settings** and make sure **Provision Profile** is set to "Automatic" and that **Code Signing Identity** is configured with the right certificate for debug and release.

[image]

Now, if you have the correct provision profile and certificate you should not have any issues...